# Efficient multiple services exposed over .NET remoting using more channels or end points?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, remoting, distributed

I am using remoting over TCP for a prototype distributed server application where I want to have varying multiple services exposed from each remoting server process.

In some cases I want the services running from the same process but I don't want whatever is using the service to care about that.

I am wondering is it more efficient to have multiple services in the same process going over the same remoting channel distinguished by endpoint URI/URL or should I be creating new channels on different ports for each service in the same process?

Using up ports isn't so much of a problem as the number of services will be low and the network and machine configuration is completely controlled.

Also its not clear to me if remoting sends the URI string for every single message or just at connection time, and whether if the remoting framework is intelligent enough to reduce work if calls are made on the same machine and even the same process?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using wireshark I found that remoting would send the URI string for every single remote exchange so its seems that there would be nothing to gain by using different sockets for two services hosted in the same process.  It would also suggest that using a short URI string is a good idea when possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can also host in separate processes over the same port, using the Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service.

Comment: Is this what remoting does anyway by using the URI string to direct the traffic if its on the same port?

Comment: No, not exactly. This is a service to allow cross-process sharing of the port.